# How do I run python code-coverage on multiple platforms

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py, python-coverage

I am using coverage.py on my code (python 2.7), inside PyDEV on Windows.

I have bits of code that run only on UNIX, usually starting with:

```
if os.name == 'posix':
```

and I want to make sure this is covered as well. Somehow to run coverage on UNIX, and merge the results to PyDEV.

I have no clue how to achieve it, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of an intergration issue.

1. You will have to run the test on different machines (but can be a remote or virtual machine) in order to test for different operating systems.
2. You may want to integrate or automate these tests as a long-term solution. There are many [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) software for this.
3. **If you need to collect coverage data from different machines or processes, coverage can combine multiple files into one for reporting. Use the `-p` flag during execution to append distinguishing information to the `.coverage` data file name.**
   Details can be found on the [`coverage.py` documentation site](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/cmd.html#cmd-combining).